# Navigate back from url params containing userID + /edit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parameters, router

I did some errorhandling, so if the user changes the userID in the url: https://localhost/*userID*/edit, the app wil change the userID to the currently logged ind user's ID.

The bug here is, that when i try to navigate back to the previous page, which is the "wrong" userID, the url will change to the current user's ID again - which makes it impossible to navigate back, once you changed the url userID. I do a subscription, which is possibly the issue, but how can i manage this bug?
Code:

```
this.route.params
  .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.profileId = this.auth.currentUserId;
    if (params['id'] !== this.auth.currentUserId) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile/' + this.profileId + '/edit']).then(() => {
        this.getProfileData(this.profileId);
      });
    }
  })
```

Comment: Try this `this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`

Comment: I have no activatedRoute variable. Want me to import it?

Comment: Didn't work - because of the subscription still i guess.